# Unity player/sprite becomes invisible after transform.position change. How do I prevent the disappearance of the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a game with "Death Blocks" that move the player to the respawn point after triggering the OnTrigger method. Here is the code:

```
public class DeathBlock : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject respawnPoint;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.name == "Player")
        {
            collision.gameObject.transform.position = respawnPoint.transform.position;
        }
    }

}
```

Edit: I found out the problem. The camera was moving on the Z axis as well so clamp the cameras Z axis position to whatever you had it to on scene startup (-10 for me), and the character remains on screen.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to include it. Edited the page Title and code. Take a look.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do either the respawn or the player have a parent game object? When you change the transform.position you change the local transform, if there is a parent object it will multiply the rotation/scale of the parent. You can also while the game is running click on 'scene' in the editor, then click on the player in the inspect, hit 'f' and find out where it is or what it doing, and whether its set active.